# Auto Import and Refactor (Move) function from one file to another in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Pycharm provides:

- Move functions/classes/variables from one file to another via
  `refactor > Move` (f6-keyboard shortcut)
- Import missing imports in the current file

Is the same available in vscode? I tried searching and came across a pull request for auto import [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/pull/636). Couldn't find anything on move refactoring though.

Is it currently possible to do so in vscode via any extensions etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is not available in the Python extension for VS Code and the latter is a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21). If you would like to see auto imports implemented, please go to that issue and upvote it.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the reply.... surely will upvote it... But I think providing that feature probably would make the IDE a bit slow else they would have done it already.. also do you recommend using vs code for large projects?

Comment: @Adarsh It has not been implemented yet as other priorities have taken precedence (e.g. the language server is tackling memory and CPU edge cases right now in prep for becoming the stable experience). As for VS Code for large projects, I'm the dev manager for the Python extension for VS Code so I'm biased, but I would say yes. :) People have told me they appreciate how nimble VS Code is for their large code bases.

Comment: I really appreciate the work done by engineers to make vs code what it is today .. the only thing that's making me not use it in production is these two features.. I don't mind paying for a version which has these two features too. I too like the way vscode is structured and how fast and lightweight it is. Is there any workaround you know of which would help moving functions or classes across multiple files on top of your head?

Comment: No workaround that I'm aware of. You can request the "Move" feature on our issue tracker.

Comment: Is there any plan to add more refactoring options to vscode?

Answer (score 15):

For anyone stumbling onto this:

The move symbol feature - as of 2023 - is now available in PyLance as well.

Select the symbol (function, class etc...) and right click -> refactor.
I made the mistake of selecting the entire function. That does not work.

Comment: Thanks! It is described here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-april-2023-release/#move-symbol-refactoring

Comment: For quick reference, this can be accessed when the cursor is on the symbol with the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+R`.

Answer (score 2):

Auto-Import for (new) missing imports is now available with [PyLance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance).